# How can I make an iframe resizable?

Tags: css, iframe, resizable

We have this group project and I was assigned to make a certain `iframe` resizable.  I've been reading lots of forum posts since last week, and I found out that `iframe` itself can't be resizable.

Is there a way to make my `iframe` resizable?

Comment: in which container you are opening iframe? even better you can put some piece of you code to get better answer..

Comment: i tried to use div, but it didn't work, what do you mean container? sorry i am new to this kind of coding, please bear with me. Thanks

Comment: Have you ever tried with jquery?

Comment: yes, actually, when I used jQuery code which is .resizable();, it worked but since the iframe is within the div tag, the src attribute of the iframe is not resizable, only the div.

Comment: can figure out how to not make it blow up to the full browser size?

Answer (score 64):

This can be done in pure CSS, like so:

```css
iframe {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Set the height and width to the minimum size you want, it only seems to grow, not shrink.

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/xpeLja5t/

This technique has [good support in all major browsers except IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize).

Comment: Does this solution still work? I have no luck with it.

Comment: @AndrewThreadgill This solution worked for me in Chrome 51.  Are you seeing something different than what is presented in Nicole's support link?

Comment: I believe it is because I am using an external site in my iframe.

Comment: I tested with an `iframe[srcdoc]` created via [iframify](https://github.com/edenspiekermann/iframify): works with Chr 54 (where it can grow but not shrink, +1) but not Fx 49 :( Related [request feature on Bugzilla@Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=680823)

Comment: This works for Chrome and Safari. Does not work for Internet Explorer, Edge or Firefox (even though Firefox does support the resize property).

Comment: There's an open bug for Firefox about this https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=680823

Comment: Thanks to the new flexbox-feature [there now is a pure-CSS-solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60803488/490291) which works for Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 24):

It took more than 1 hour [to find something](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325334/490291) which led me to a working solution:

- Pure CSS as it should be
- For all modern browsers with full flexbox support, like Firefox, Chrome, etc.
- Does not work for older browsers like IE10 and below, though

```css
.resizer { display:flex; margin:0; padding:0; resize:both; overflow:hidden }
.resizer > .resized { flex-grow:1; margin:0; padding:0; border:0 }

.ugly { background:red; border:4px dashed black; }
```

```html
<div class="resizer ugly">
  <iframe class="resized" src="https://wikipedia.org/"></iframe>
</div>
```

In Chrome this solution still has some issues at my side.  Use **Run code snippet** and then **Full Page** (so it does not seem to work if the `IFRAME` is embedded in other `IFRAME`s).  Also the resize handle (in the right bottom corner) is shown a bit subtle, and resizing often stops to follow the mouse.

[In Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=680823) you can resize the `iframe` now using pure CSS, too.

> Wikipedia was the only URL I found which has no CSP against `iframe`-embedding yet.  If they ever add one, the `iframe` becomes empty and your Browser's console will log the CSP error.  In this case, please update my answer with some working URL.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, this really works. Is there something similar for draggability?

Comment: @user185953 IMHO not this easy.  AFAICS dragging needs JavaScript (to receive the drag).  As `IFRAME`s are interactive and receive all mouse events (like drag), you need something outside the `IFRAME`'s control (some additional drag-`DIV`).  From JavaScript, drags of this drag-`DIV` then can be applied to the the resizer-`DIV` accordingly to simulate dragging.  If the drag-`DIV` is made to (transparently) cover the whole `IFRAME` and is (in z-order) in front of the `IFRAME`, it can receive all the mouse events before the `IFRAME` (but you cannot interact with the `IFRAME` in that situation).

Answer (score 13):

These steps will make an iframe resizable:

1. Create a div for resizing. eg:

   ```html
   <div class="resizable"></div>
   ```
2. Apply the style tag for style of div.

   ```
   .ui-resizable-helper {
       border: 1px dotted gray;
   }
   .resizable {
       display: block;
       width: 400px;
       height: 400px;
       padding: 30px;
       border: 2px solid gray;
       overflow: hidden;
       position: relative;
   }
   iframe {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
   }
   ```
3. Include jQuery & jQuery UI

   ```html
   <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"rel="stylesheet" />
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   ```
4. Execute `Resizable`

   ```js
   $(function () {
       $(".resizable").resizable({
           animate: true,
           animateEasing: 'swing',
           animateDuration: 500
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: `$(".resizable").resizable({ ... imateDuration: 500});` should be `animateDuration`

Comment: If you only need resizable panes, adding jQuery UI might be overkill, but it is a nice library indeed.

Answer (score 10):

With jQuery UI...

**HTML:**

```
<div class="resizable" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
    <iframe src="http://www.example.com/" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".resizable").resizable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        ui.element.append($("<div/>", {
            id: "iframe-barrier",
            css: {
                position: "absolute",
                top: 0,
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0,
                "z-index": 10
        }
        }));
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $("#iframe-barrier", ui.element).remove();
    },
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        $("iframe", ui.element).width(ui.size.width).height(ui.size.height);
    }
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B5vHQ/97/

Explanation:

Since jQuery UI's `resizable` plugin won't work on an iframe directly, wrap the iframe in a div and resize the div instead.  The `resize` event in the code above ensures that the iframe resizes to match the div.

There's an additional problem with this method, however - iframes don't pass mouse movement events to their parent element.  To work around that, the `start` and `stop` events cover the iframe up with another element during the resize, so that the `resizable` plugin can track mouse movement correctly.

For some reason, giving the wrapper div an explicit size is necessary for the resizing to work.  In most cases, that means that the iframe needs the same size set, so thatit matches the size of the div right from the start.

Comment: +1 cant believe this is the only barrier solution and it didnt have any votes! this is a big deal for not "losing" track of the mouse when dragging too quickly over another iframe. thanks @Brilliand!

Comment: @happytimeharry I didn't actually solve the problem for multiple iframes interfering with each other - the barrier in my answer only prevents the one iframe from interfering with its own resizing.

Answer (score 7):

In case you haven't found the solution yet, I've had success with:

Jquery:

```js
$("#my-div-frame-wrapper").resizable({
    alsoResize : '#myframe'
});
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="my-div-frame-wrapper">
    <iframe id="myframe"></iframe>
</div>
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

I found your solution:

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content" 
     style="border-style:solid; height:400px; width:400px">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
    <iframe src="test.aspx" id="myfr" scrolling="no"
            frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" >
        Your Browser Do not Support Iframe
    </iframe>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```js
$(function() {
    $("#resizable").resizable();

    $("#resizable").resizable({
        resize: function(event, ui) {
            $("#myfr").css({ "height": ui.size.height,"width":ui.size.width});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It still didn't work out, my previous code was better :( thanks though

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I've found is to set the width and height of the iframe to 100% and put the iframe within a div tag.  This is the basic solution you see with tools like CKEditor.

For an example, I have some jQuery dialogs that do just that on the [Utah's Disclosures Site](http://disclosures.utah.gov/Search/PublicSearch/FolderDetails/1390).  If you click on a report or statement of or, you'll see a dialog that pops up with an iframe in it.  Hope it helps.

Comment: <div class="demo"><iframe src="http://www.xxxx.com/xxxx/xxxx.php" name="xxxx" id="xxxx" style="border:0px;frameborder:0px;visibility:hidden;" style="border:1; top:0; left:0; right:0; height:100%; width:100%"></iframe></div>

Comment: but it still didn't work, the only part that is resizable is the <div> part

Answer (score 0):

very easy,

first -

add jquery and **jquery-ui** -

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

then -

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#resizable" ).resizable();
});
</script>
```

last -

```
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
<h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>
```

**Its done!**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Resizable - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
#resizable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
#resizable h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#resizable" ).resizable();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
<h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

form http://jqueryui.com/resizable/