# SVG: Dragging a rect works only if dragging slowly

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an SVG rect element that I need to drag around the screen. The problem is that it doesn't work when dragging fast. I posted the code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/c6XW3/3/).

The example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758090/dragging-a-div-in-jquery-fine-when-mouse-is-slow-but-fails-on-fast-mouse-move) solves the problem in JQuery. I adapted the solution to SVG but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

This is the HTML code:

```
<svg id="svg" width="800" height="800" style="border: 1px dashed black;"
onmousemove="move(evt)" onmouseup="endMove(evt)" onmouseout="endMove(evt)">

<rect id="r" x="100" y="100" height="150" width="150" onmousedown="mouseDown(evt)"/>

</svg>
```

And the javascript:

```
  var click=false; // flag to indicate when shape has been clicked
  var clickX, clickY; // stores cursor location upon first click
  var moveX=0, moveY=0; // keeps track of overall transformation
  var lastMoveX=0, lastMoveY=0; // stores previous transformation (move)


function mouseDown(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    click=true;
    clickX = evt.clientX; 
    clickY = evt.clientY;
}

function move(evt){
evt.preventDefault();
if(click){
    moveX = lastMoveX + ( evt.clientX - clickX );
    moveY = lastMoveY + ( evt.clientY - clickY );
    evt.target.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + moveX + "," + moveY + ")");
  }
}

function endMove(evt){
    click=false;
    lastMoveX = moveX;
    lastMoveY = moveY;
}
```

Comment: your fiddle works fine at any speed for me, unless I mouse out of the page. Since your code doesn't take that into account, the dragging does not resume on mousein.

Comment: Agree with Mike. I think the issue is your `mouseout` handler is calling endMove prematurely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you'll need to look into your `endMove` handler and clean up the logic there.

However, simply removing the handler isn't *quite* the answer (since you'll find yourself with a "jerky" experience if you continue mousing around).

Here are two things I would recommend (with a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uUbRy/)

**Capture the element that has focus.**

In `mouseDown`, I set `elementWithFocus = evt.target` to use in your mousemove handler.

**Address the endMove issue.**

For that, I've updated your handler with the following condition check:

```
if(evt.type == 'mouseout' && click) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you move your mouse quickly, the cursor can end up temporarily outside of the box, before it catches up with the position. This causes an onmouseout event to be fired, which stops the dragging.
To fix this you can simply remove the attribute `onmouseout="endMove(evt)"` from your svg object.